# Failing to install python-igraph

Tags: linux, python-2.7, igraph

I'm trying to install python-igraph. After I run `sudo pip install python-igraph` I got the following log:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-igraph
  Downloading python-igraph-0.7.1-1.tar.gz (375kB): 375kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-igraph

Installing collected packages: python-igraph
  Running setup.py install for python-igraph
    Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.
    We will now try to download and compile the C core from scratch.
    Version number of the C core: 0.7.1-1

    Version 0.7.1-1 of the C core of igraph is not found among the nightly builds.
    Use the --c-core-version switch to try a different version.

    Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.

    WARNING: we were not able to detect where igraph is installed on
    your machine (if it is installed at all). We will use the fallback
    library and include pathss hardcoded in setup.py and hope that the
    C core of igraph is installed there.

    If the compilation fails and you are sure that igraph is installed
    on your machine, adjust the following two variables in setup.py
    accordingly and try again:

    - LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_DIRS
    - LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_DIRS

Build type: dynamic extension                                    
    Include path: /usr/include/igraph /usr/local/include/igraph
    Library path:
    Linked dynamic libraries: igraph
    Linked static libraries:
    Extra compiler options:
    Extra linker options:
    building 'igraph._igraph' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/igraphmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/igraphmodule.o
    src/igraphmodule.c:25:20: fatal error: igraph.h: No such file or directory
     #include <igraph.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cTa4Ba-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/formula.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/configuration.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/summary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/layout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/cut.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/datatypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/clustering.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/statistics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/matching.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/operators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/isomorphism.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/colortests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/homepage.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/attributes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/vertexseq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/structural.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/separators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/atlas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/layouts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/rng.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/games.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/iterators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/edgeseq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/indexing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/spectral.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/cliques.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/flow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/generators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/matching.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/foreign.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/bipartite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/decomposition.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/shell.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/edge.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/shapes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/coord.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/metamagic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/text.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/colors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/vertex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/baseclasses.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/nexus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/gephi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/texttable.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

running build_ext

Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.

We will now try to download and compile the C core from scratch.

Version number of the C core: 0.7.1-1



Version 0.7.1-1 of the C core of igraph is not found among the nightly builds.

Use the --c-core-version switch to try a different version.



Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.



WARNING: we were not able to detect where igraph is installed on

your machine (if it is installed at all). We will use the fallback

library and include pathss hardcoded in setup.py and hope that the

C core of igraph is installed there.



If the compilation fails and you are sure that igraph is installed

on your machine, adjust the following two variables in setup.py

accordingly and try again:



- LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_DIRS

- LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_DIRS



Build type: dynamic extension                                    

Include path: /usr/include/igraph /usr/local/include/igraph

Library path:

Linked dynamic libraries: igraph

Linked static libraries:

Extra compiler options:

Extra linker options:

building 'igraph._igraph' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/igraphmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/igraphmodule.o

src/igraphmodule.c:25:20: fatal error: igraph.h: No such file or directory

 #include <igraph.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cTa4Ba-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph
Storing complete log in /home/sergey/.pip/pip.log
```

And I have similar situation if I do it with `sudo python setup.py install`.

Apparently the problem is with C core.

How can I install the correct version of it so that I can install igraph?

I use Linux Mint 16 64-bit, python 2.7.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need igraph libraries before compiling python-igraph.

Try `sudo apt-get install -y libigraph0-dev` and try install python-igraph again.

Comment: I have the same error. what is the corresponding library for windows?

Comment: I have the same error, but I am a mac user. Any idea what I could do ?

Comment: In ubuntu 18.04 I still get the same error. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @YonatanSimson were you able to fix the error ?

Comment: @Salih I am on python 3.8 Ubuntu 20.04 and the problem doesn't appear in this configuration

Answer (score 6):

Using Ubuntu 16 and Python3.

```
pip3 install python-igraph
```

results in error building whell. However,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-igraph
```

worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

For windows users

1. [Download](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) the unofficial `python-igraph` (according to [igraph official installation instruction](http://igraph.org/python/#pyinstallwin)), please select the appropriate .whl file based on environment (python version, 64bit vs. 32bit).
2. Open command console and `cd` into .whl's folder
3. Execute the following command:

   ```
   pip install python_igraph-0.7.1.post.xxx.whl
   ```

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded both 
python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl and tried to install them with pip install on a Windows 10 virtual box that is running Python 3.6.2 (pycairo is installed). I got this error message back python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Does this mean that Python 3.6 is not supported ?

Comment: CP is for compiler version, It seems you have download a wrong version. you need to download cp36 not cp34

Answer (score 3):

In ubuntu 16.04:

For python 2:

```
apt-get install build-essential python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

For python 3:

```
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: credits: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/159#issuecomment-424146403

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Users :

Add the repository of igraph to apt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:igraph/ppa
```

Then update and install the python-igraph package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-igraph
```

Comment: I want to use it for python3. what changes occur to these commands?